# Airflow collision for same task name in the same DAG, but different execution dates

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow 1.10.3.
I have a DAG which runs everyday at 05:30 UTC. Now, sometimes, the last day's run overflows into the current day's run and then Airflow starts throwing errors like :

```
[2020-11-05 08:31:34,127] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3847763: Subtask xxxxx.xxxxxx     raise RuntimeError(error)
[2020-11-05 08:31:34,127] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 3847763: Subtask xxxxx.xxxxxx RuntimeError: Found existing tasks running with state RUNNING - [<TaskInstance: yyyyyyy.xxxxx.xxxxxx 2020-11-02 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>, <TaskInstance: yyyyyyy.xxxxx.xxxxxx 2020-11-03 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>]. Therefore skipping this task instance
[2020-11-05 08:31:37,679] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-11-05 08:31:37,678] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Can the newer versions of Airflow, like 1.10.12 distinguish two tasks with the same name but different execution date as different task instances?

I would then consider updating the Airflow version.

Comment: A task_istance is bound to a dag_run which should make it unique by design. Could you post the code of the DAG?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis as you can see from the error log, if two of them are running having the same name, it is throwing a RuntimeError because the other with the same name is already running.

Comment: It's definitely not an issue of the Airflow Version, I am using 1.10.2 and never experienced such behaviour. How is the task defined?